# NV.D3 Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to build a simple bar chart using based on reading in CSV data.  Right now I'm just including the data in my script.  When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here's the script:

```
var data;

function showChart() {
  var theCsv =
    "name,value\n" +
    "Foo,43\n" +
    "bar,76\n" +
    "foo2,88\n" +
    "bar2,59\n";
  var csvString;
  var content = [{
    key: "totals",
    values: []
  }];

  var input = d3.csv.parse(theCsv, function(d) {
    return {
      name: d.name,
      value: d.value
    };
  });

nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
      .x(function(d) {
        return d.name
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return d.value
      })
      /*.showvalues(true)*/

    d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(input)
      .transition(1000)
      .call(chart)

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;

  });

  fileDisplayArea.innerText = csvString
}
```

As far as I can tell from debugging, the error is occuring on the `.call(chart)` line, but I have no clue what the problem is.  I've found a couple of links talking about the version of D3, but I've tried several different ones, and I'm still getting the error.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnyaya/c9y0yv68/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to wrap your data into another object like so:

```
var input = d3.csv.parse(theCsv, function(d) {
    return {
      name: d.name,
      value: d.value
    };
  });

// get it into the form required by `nvd3`
input = [{ key: "Some Key", values: input }]
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9y0yv68/1/) with the one extra line above added.

I couldn't find any documentation on *why*, but that seems to be the pattern used (based on [this example on the site](http://nvd3.org/examples/discreteBar.html)).

Comment: @adilapapaya please check my problem this is also same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635193/how-to-resolve-an-error-like-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefi?noredirect=1#comment64654995_38635193